# How to achieve custom dialog at the bottom of the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

Which component do I choose to achieve custom dialog at the bottom as shown in the below image? Shall I choose `alertdialog`,`popupwindow`, or `fragmentdialog`?

[image: dialogAtBottom]

Comment: you can use popup window & give in animation for bottom to show

Comment: Use BottomSheetDialog with custom layout.

Comment: https://mayojava.github.io/android/bottom-sheets-android/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Try this**

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(YourView);

dialog.show();
```

Comment: For a great tutorial see: https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295

Comment: @ak sacha GREAT straightforward answer.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I didn't there was a built in component in Android to do so. Good to know! Also, check this out:

https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295#

I would recommend `FragmentDialog` without a doubt.

It's so much easier to create a customized `Dialog` regarding location & layout design.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code for run custom ButtomSheetDialog (run inside Activity)

```
 var CustomSelectProfilePicBottomSheetDialog  =   BottomSheetDialog(this)
  val   layoutButtomSheetView  = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ly_custom_buttom_sheet_frg_dialog, null)
   CustomSelectProfilePicBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(layoutButtomSheetView)
  CustomSelectProfilePicBottomSheetDialog.show()
```